# C# P2P chat application design

Tags: c#, tcp, chat, p2p

I want to create a simple chat application that doesn't use an explicit server. The main requirement is that the user can simultaneously chat with many friends (just like on Skype etc.). I do not mean a conference chat here, just multiple separate chat-windows.

Currently, I want only a LAN messaging application but I'd appreciate, if the design was easy to extend to Internet connections.

I wonder what design is appropriate for such an application.

- What do you think about a solution, where each user app has a `TcpListener` (the implicit server) and multiple `TcpClient` objects - one for each friend he/she is talking to.
- What about authenticating the remote users? Should the chatting app generate a certificate (X509 or sth) or just assume that the users in a LAN are to be trusted :)

Kindest regards,

Comment: I think your approach as far as the TCP connections go, is sound.

Comment: Your "solution" regarding TcpListener and TcpClient is not viable/scalable due to its firewall/NAT unfriendliness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpListener` + `WebClient(or HttpWebRequest)` can provide you more tools for authentication/security.
Basic Authentication, Ntlm, Integrated Windows Authentication, https etc. and they are more firewall friendly.

Comment: Chat over HTTP is fine? It sounds like a WebService .. not an app ??

Comment: Why not? Just a text based protocol over TCP. HttpListener is not much different than TcpListener and WebClient than TcpClient. Post any data binary/text with WebCLient and read from HttpListener, just you would do with TcpListener.

Comment: Apart from the change of classes, the multiplicity of the instances is okay? Meaning one HttpListener and many HttpWebClients?

Answer (score 3):

You should see start with

[how do i make my own P2P software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673881/how-do-i-make-my-own-p2p-software)

[WCF / WPF Chat Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWPFChat.aspx)

[P2P Communication - Proxy Listeners and Proxy Clients](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ProxyListener.aspx)

Hope this proves good starting point

Happy coding